# Firefox adds 1px on my submit button

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, webforms

I'm trying to design my form via CSS.
Problem is that I need a "standard" submit and a hyperlink which is styled like a button with CSS.

My CSS currently looks like that:

```
    form .buttons input[type=submit], form .buttons a { padding: 0; margin: 0; } 
    form .buttons input[type=submit], form .buttons a { font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; color: #565656; }
    form .buttons input[type=submit] { border: 1px solid black; }
    form .buttons a { border: 1px solid black; }
```

In Firefox I have the problem that there is a 1px padding added around the submit button (like you can see on the screenshot).

[image: Firefox CSS problem]

Is there a solution how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Could be the line height as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
input[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner { 
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try also "line-height: normal;" it fixed a bug in IE as well.